# Pandas merge on values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, merge

I have two tables with eCommerce site data, one with more categorical data about the stores and another with metrics on each store's performance.

Stores table:

```
region  country_code    outlet_id   creation_date   brand_id    
0   EEMEA   KZ          231405      2020-10-29      147598  
1   EEMEA   UA          311975      2021-05-27      216498  
2   SWE     PL          246038      2020-12-07      117980
3   SWE     IT          292770      2021-04-15      288500  
4   SWE     ES          300967      2021-05-03      298416
```

Metrics table:

```
store_id    month   total_orders    delivered_orders    bad_rating_orders   
0   196105  2020-06 12              11                  2
1   196148  2020-06 1               0                   0
2   194503  2020-06 14              13                  1
3   199178  2020-06 6               6                   0
4   194898  2020-06 14              13                  0
```

I need to join the two tables based on the store_id but some of the store_ids correspond to an outlet_id and others to a brand_id.

Is there a way for me to merge/join on store_id with values from outlet_id or brand_id where the store_id matches.

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Comment: In your example none of `store_id` matches `outlet_id`/`brand_id`. Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: Also provide the `merge` command that you tried and how it failed